# Bitbucket POST Pull Request not working [kirchbergerknorr]

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

as stated [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Work+with+pull+requests)

for public repository - https://bitbucket.org/kirchbergerknorr/test
i setted up hook for Pull Request POST:
[image: hook settings]

then i created pull request
and here is dump for GET and POST vars:

```
GET: Array
(
    [type] => pullrequest
    [project] => test
)

POST: Array
(
)
```

i expect that it should work the same as POST hook works:

```
POST: Array
(
    [payload] => {"repository": {"website": "", ...
```

but POST var is totally empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaleb Elwert post [an answer in bugtracker](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/9255/pull-request-post-hook-not-sending-any):

> For now, I'm going to leave this as-is. However, this is not a bug.
>   The original POST hook provided the JSON data in a "payload" POST
>   variable, however this is an older method of doing things. In the
>   newer Pull Request POST hook, we simply provide a Content-Type of
>   application/json and include the data as the raw POST data. We have no
>   intention of making any backwards incompatible changes with either of
>   these hooks, so your best bet is to have a separate endpoint which
>   manages pull request hooks. This is a modified version of your sample
>   code which will pull the json into the $data variable.
>
> https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Pull+Request+POST+hook+management

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
if (!$json) {
    return false;
}

$data = json_decode($json);
```